# update value in datagrid gives error in tables with foreign keys

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

i am trying to write a code in visual studio c# where I have 3 tables 
customer , product, order all three are related

Now i have created datagridview and fetch values from database , and when i edit datagrid , it updates database too, but when i try to update Product_id which is primary key of product and foreign key of order.

It gives error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn = new SqlConnection("user id=sa;" +
                                       "password=sa@123;server=sudhanshu-lappy;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=alpha; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {





            //DataTable dt = null;

            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM orders", conn);
            //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //dt = new DataTable();

            //dt.Load(reader);

            //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


            //DataGridViewButtonColumn clbt_delet = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            //clbt_delet.HeaderText = "DELETE";

            //clbt_delet.Text = "Delete";
            //clbt_delet.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            //dataGridView1.Columns.Add(clbt_delet);


            //da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from orders", conn);
            //SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            //ds = new DataSet();
            //da.Fill(ds);
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            //now u can save changes to back end with


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da.Update(ds);
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da.Update(ds);
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da.Update(ds);
        }

        private void ordersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from orders", conn);
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void productToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from product", conn);
            SqlCommandBuilder cb1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void customerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from customer", conn);
            SqlCommandBuilder cb2 = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }




    }
}
```

Secondly I am only able to update order table by update operation, its not happening with other two tables

Sudhanshu

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Which error do you get in your code? Can you also remove the code in your question which is not relevant to your problem?

Comment: Why are you updating PRODUCTID

Comment: product_id is in order id too as foreign key so i want that if i update product_id of order then product id of product should also update, is that possible ?

Comment: @carl The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__orders__product___1A14E395." The conflict occurred in database "dbo.product", column 'product_id' database "alpha".

here i am unable to update product_id but order_amount i can

Comment: @user2570155 your problem is related to `Validation` and maybe your `Database design` which are not easy to understand and debug if the debugger doesn't work directly in your project. Briefly speaking, your updated data have some field (known as `foreign key`) having some value which doesn't exist in the table to which the foreign key references. You have to validate your submit data first. I think you should try to understand `Foreign key` and related-problem first and come back to your problem. You may also want to run the query in the environment of your db engine.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had this same problem.  Try changing the foreign keys in the 'database'.xsd file in visual studio.  You have to update them in the .xsd file, the actual database, and then rebuild the update queries in the .xsd file before it will work.  It's a pain, but it's something that I had to do many times.